# PJSIP library compile error for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, pjsip

I am trying to compile pjsip library for iOS, but getting an error and I am following below steps

**Step 1:**
Create a new file config_site.h in the project folder /pjlib/include/pj/ with the following code:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1 
#include <pjconfig_site_sample.h>
```

**Step 2:** Open terminal

```
$ cd /path/to/my/pjsip/dir
```

**Step 3:**

```
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
ARCH="-arch x86_64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
```

**Step 4:**

```
make dep && make clean && make
```

After this command, I am getting the error

```
for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build third_party/build pjmedia/build pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
    if /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -C $dir dep; then \
        true; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
done
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f /Users/murtuza/Desktop/PJSip/iOS/pjproject-2.9/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB app=pjlib depend
.pjlib-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.depend:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make: *** [dep] Error 1
```

Am i missing something or else. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#missing-sep-err

> This happens because of corrupt dependency file, probably because make dep stopped or was stopped abruptly previously. The solution is either to delete the offending file manually or to run make distclean to clean everything. Either case, you'd have to run make dep again to rebuild the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Settings -> User Defined ->
[VALID ARCHS - arm64] -> debug section -> add also x86_64